# Eureka server cannot discover clients when running services on docker containers

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, microservices

I'm trying to develop application which have 3 microservices, postgres database and eureka server for discovering clients. Locally all works perfect. The problem appears when i'm deploying services on docker containers. One container per service, for postgres and for eureka. I'm create a network in docker and join all containers. The question is what should I do to discover my microservices in eureka server? If anyone will want to help I will provide more details to resolve the problem.
That's my docker-compose

```
version: "3.7"
networks:
  default:
    name: microservices_nw
    driver: bridge
services:
  postgresService:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxx
      - POSTGRES_USER=xxx
      - POSTGRES_DB=work
    restart: unless-stopped
  # EUREKA SERVER#####
  eureka-server:
    image: eureka-server:latest
    container_name: eureka-server
    expose:
      - 8761
    restart: unless-stopped
  # APP*****************************************
  credit-microservice:
    image: credit-microservice:latest
    container_name: credit-microservice
    expose:
      - 8600
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgresService/work
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=xxx
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=xxx
    restart: unless-stopped

  product-micorservice:
    image: product-microservice:latest
    container_name: product-micorservice
    expose:
      - 8080
    environment:
        - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgresService/work
        - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=xxx
        - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=xxx
    restart: unless-stopped

  customer-microservice:
    image: customer-microservice:latest
    container_name: customer-microservice
    expose:
      - 8081
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgresService/work
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=xxx
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=xxx
      - EUREKA_INSTANCE_PREFER_IP_ADDRESS=true
      - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE=http://eureka-server/eureka
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Dockerfile for customer-microservice

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/customer-service.jar customer-service.jar
EXPOSE 8081
CMD java -jar customer-service.jar
```

Dockerfile for product-microservice

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/product-service.jar product-service.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java -jar product-service.jar
```

Dockerfile for eureka-server

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/eureka-server.jar eureka-server.jar
EXPOSE 8761
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "eureka-server.jar"]
```

Dockerfile for credit-microservice

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
ADD target/credit-service.jar credit-service.jar
EXPOSE 8600
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "credit-service.jar"]
```

And application.yml for customer-service

```
server:
  port: 8081

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: ${EUREKA_SERVER:http://localhost:8761/eureka}

  ## PostgreSQL
spring:
  application:
    name: customer-service
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/work
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: validate
    properties:
      hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation: true
```

Comment: `If anyone will want to help I will provide more details to resolve the problem.` Provide more details or noone will help you. Sorry but this question is too broad as for now. Show your dockerfiles, dockercompose files and so on...

Comment: i think the problem is 
here ERROR 6 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}
how to override this url to use container address?

Comment: It's right there in your application.yml for the clients. You need to put in the ip address for the docker of the eureka service. You can also put it in an application.yaml outside of the jar - I use a 'config' subdir.

Comment: Put `EUREKA_SERVER=eureka-server:8761` in docker-compose `customer-microservice` environment variables.

Comment: Kieveli if you mean something like - JAVA_OPTS=
        -DEUREKA_SERVER=192.168.99.100:8761 (that's my docker-machine ip) it doesn't work . michalk your solution doesn't work too.I read in book that the proper way to play with docker is to prefer ip addresses instead of hostnames because hostnames are randomly generated. How to provide proper URL to register my services to eureka server?

Comment: Okey, after hard fight with this I solved the problem. :D